# XPath to get one level of childnodes

Tags: php, xpath, domxpath

Using DOMXPath::query is it possible to get just one level deep of childNodes?

For example if I had a document like:

```
<div>
    <span>
        <cite>
        </cite>
    </span>
    <span>
        <cite>
        </cite>
    </span>
</div>
```

I would want the NodeList to contain just the spans and not the cites.

Should also mention that it won't always be the same elements (divs, spans, etc).  I would need it to work with any type of element.

This is what I tried and it didn't seem to work:

```
//*[not(ancestor::div)]
```

Answer (score 3):

If you use

```
/div/*
```

then you get a list of all direct children in this element but these children contain their children. I think that you can't remove children of child

There is used default axis, it is called `child::`. This axis returns only elements in 1 level under the current node

`*` matches all elements but neither attributes nor text()

You have to specify path to your node and be careful about `//node` because it means `descendant::node` and it returns all nodes of this name in this tree

Comment: Thanks for child:: axis suggestion.  This should be the accepted answer.

Answer (score 2):

Your question is a bit under-specified, so there are several ways to interpret it. If you want all direct child elements of the current element (with all of their sub-elements), then use

```
*/*
```

For your example, this gives you

```
<span>
    <cite>
    </cite>
</span>
```

and

```
<span>
    <cite>
    </cite>
</span>
```

If you want all child *nodes*, then use `node()` instead of `*`:

```
*/node()
```

For your example, this gives you both sub-elements as above, alongside with newline/indentation `text()` nodes.

If, however, you want to have **only** the child nodes and not their children as well (i.e. only the `span` elements, but without their child elements), you must use two expressions:

1. select the direct child elements via `*/*`
2. process the those child elements and select only the text nodes and not the grandchildren elements via `text()`

My PHP is a bit rusty, but it should work a bit like this:

```
$doc = new DOMDocument;
// set up $doc
$xpath = new DOMXPath($doc);

// perform step #1
$childElements = $xpath->query('*/*');

$directChildren = array();
foreach ($childElements as $child) {
  // perform step #2
  $textChildren = $xpath->query('text()', $child);
  foreach ($textChildren as $text) {
    $directChildren[] = $text;
  }
}
// now, $directChildren contains all text nodes
```

Comment: Thanks nd, the last one is what I'm looking for.  Just the direct child nodes, no grandchildren.  Can you expand more on that example?  I've >very< new to XPath and it's not quite clicking yet.